# NoClassDefFoundError error while running JAVA console app

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I created little HelloWorld example and I am having problem running it from command prompt (on Windows). When I attempt to run it by:

**java tcpServer** from command prompt I get **NoClassDefFoundError**
I am able to compile it with javac, and class file gets generated.

Somewhere I was reading that I have to put path to my class folder into CLASSPATH environment variable. I've done it and rebooted machine, but I still get the same error.

I also was trying to run it by **java -cp c:\MyFolderWhereClassFileIs HelloWorld**, it doesn't work.

I've looked into ENV variables and I have following:
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26;
JRE_HOME:C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6;
CLASSPATH: C:\HelloWorld;

**So, how do I run this?
Any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks.**

PS. The most annoying thing to me is, if I create java project in eclipse, and create HelloWorld example, then it runs fine...

UPDATE:

Here is the code. It does have package specified.

```
package test.com;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

My HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class files are here:
C:\workspace\TestApp\src\test\com

One thing I learned so far is that I can't run it from within com folder or test folder. I have to be in src folder class file can be found... but I am still not able to run it... always the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your class have a package name? That is, a statement at the top which reads

`package <mypkgname>;`?

If so, then you have to **(A)** create the correct directory structure and **(B)** prefix the class name with the package name in your `java` command.

For example, if your Java file looks like this:

```
package hello;
public class HelloWorld {
    ...
}
```

Then a basic directory structure would resemble:

```
src/hello/
src/hello/HelloWorld.java
src/hello/HelloWorld.class
```

And your bash command would be:

```
cd src
java hello.HelloWorld
```

---

Otherwise, if your class has no package name, it will be placed in the default package. In this case, you simply have to `cd` to the directory where your class file resides, and run `java HelloWorld`.

Comment: I tried as you said: In my case I typed: "cd src" and then, "java test.com.HelloWorld"... I get the same error. Please take a look at my update above.. And thanks for your response

Comment: figured it out... I will mark your answer as correct one. Eclipse was placing class files into bin folder, and I didn't notice that right away... I copied class file back to where java file is and then run HelloWorld as you said it. Thanks.

Comment: It's often helpful to learn how to compile+run from the command-line before using an IDE.